# http post to upload file to google sites on iphone

Tags: iphone, http, post, nsurlconnection, google-api

I am trying to upload a kml file to Google Sites.  The api is here- http://code.google.com/apis/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingFiles and they give this example-

```
POST /feeds/content/domainName/siteName HTTP/1.1
Host: sites.google.com
GData-Version: 1.4
Authorization: <your authorization header here>
Content-Length: 7221984
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=END_OF_PART
--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
term="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#attachment" label="attachment"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#parent" type="application/atom+xml"
href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/domainName/siteName/PARENT_ENTRY_ID"/>
<title>PDF File</title>
<summary>HR packet</summary>
</entry>

--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/pdf

... pdf contents here ...

--END_OF_PART--
```

I am trying to use NSMutableURLRequest to perform this post.  Here is my code-

```
NSString *boundary=@"END_OF_PART";    
NSMutableString *bodyString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:50];
[bodyString appendFormat:@"--%@\n",boundary];
[bodyString appendString:@"Content-Type: application/atom+xml\n"];
[bodyString appendString:@"<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">\n"];
[bodyString appendString:@"<category scheme=\"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind\"\n"];
[bodyString appendString:@"term=\"http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#attachment\" label=\"attachment\"/>\n"];
[bodyString appendString:@"<link rel=\"http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#parent\" type=\"application/atom+xml\"\n"];
[bodyString appendString:@"href=\"https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/itourlocal/kmlfiles\"/>\n"];
[bodyString appendFormat:@"<title>%@.kml</title>\n",theNewTour.tourName];
[bodyString appendString:@"</entry>\n"];
[bodyString appendFormat:@"--%@\n",boundary];
[bodyString appendString:@"Content-Type: application/kml\n"];
NSString *kmlString=[KMLExporter kmlForPoints:self.theNewTour.locations andRoutes:polylines];
[bodyString appendFormat:@"%@\n",kmlString];
[bodyString appendFormat:@"--%@--",boundary];
NSData *postData = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];  
NSString *postLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];    
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];  
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/itourlocal/kmlfiles"]];  
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  
[request addValue:@"multipart/related; boundary=\"END_OF_PART\"" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  
[request setValue:@"sites.google.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[request setValue:@"1.4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoogleLogin auth=%@",authString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSLog(@"%@",authString);
[request setHTTPBody:postData];  
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request];
```

Here is the entire text of the body string before it is converted into data-

```
--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
term="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#attachment" label="attachment"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#parent" type="application/atom+xml"
href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/itourlocal/kmlfiles"/>
<title>bar test.kml</title>
</entry>
--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/kml
<kml> <Document> <Placemark> <name>Mezzanine</name> <address>444 Jessie Street, San Francisco</address> <description>(null)</description> <Point> <coordinates>-122.408028,37.782402,0</coordinates> </Point> </Placemark><Placemark> <name>1015 Folsom</name> <address>1015 Folsom Street, San Francisco</address> <description>(null)</description> <Point> <coordinates>-122.405678,37.778072,0</coordinates> </Point> </Placemark><Style id='roadStyle'> <LineStyle> <color>7fcf0064</color> <width>6</width> </LineStyle></Style><Placemark>  <styleURL>#roadStyle</styleURL>  <LineString> <coordinates>-122.407997,37.782379 -122.409248,37.781399 -122.409248,37.781399 -122.408707,37.780979 -122.408157,37.780540 -122.407700,37.780170 -122.407158,37.779739 -122.406631,37.779308 -122.406158,37.778938 -122.405617,37.778500 -122.405617,37.778500 -122.406036,37.778172 -122.406036,37.778172 -122.405800,37.777981 </coordinates> </LineString> </Placemark></Document> </kml>
--END_OF_PART--
```

This request returns "Multipart must have Atom and media part"

I have tried many different variation but keep getting errors.  Any suggestions for getting this right?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out-
I needed to add a second line break after the content-type line.  not sure why, but it works now.